# iOS + How to answer System call using an App from wearable device

Tags: ios, swift, fitbit

First of all, this is not about VoIP.

Requirement: The user taps on a wearable device to receive an incoming call, just like FitBit.

I have tried `CallKit`'s `CXProvider` and its delegate but it seems only work with VoIP related apps.

How we can answer the call using an app? I saw in FitBit wearable it is allowed to receive an incoming system call.

Spend a whole day to search an answer not able to figure it out. Please don't suggest private APIs.